# What is the address of back() in an empty container?

Tags: c++, containers, standard-library

I mistakenly took the address of the reference returned by the `back()` operator in an empty container and was surprised to see that the address wasn't zero.

If a container e.g. std::deque is empty, what does `back()` return?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it returns the last element.

on this page: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BackInsertionSequence.html

precondition: !a.empty()

Equivalent to *(--a.end()).

since the precondition is the deque is not empty, then it means it's undefined behavior.

Comment: It also means that is it most likely one element just before the "logical" place for the first element. I should say that the behavior of `front` is logically the same though the address will be the "logical" place I was talking about (for an array-like container).

Answer (score 1):

Calling `front` or `back` on an empty standard container results in undefined behavior.